# Upload picture to Facebook page using Graph API

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to upload pictures to `Facebook` fan page from my app. I am able to upload the pictures on user's wall by using `FBSDKShareAPI`. Code-

```
@IBAction func sharePhoto(_ sender: UIButton)
{
if FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
content.photos = [FBSDKSharePhoto(image: myImageView.image, userGenerated: true)]
FBSDKShareAPI.share(with: content, delegate: self)
} else {
print("require publish_actions permissions")
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to post to the page's wall. I came across this code -

```
curl -i -X POST \
-d "url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fimages%2Ffb_icon_325x325.png" \
-d "caption=test%20photo%20upload" \
-d "access_token=<user_photos_token>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/(pagelink)"
```

I tried with this code in the terminal and was able to post the images, but couldn't find it for`Xcode`.

I was also able to post the image using the Graph API Explorer.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your if part in method ?

Comment: @Jecky sorry i missed that line. I have updated it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos#Creating

Comment: @CBroe thanks for reply. i got an error. "Cannot convert value of type '(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, Any, Error) -> Void' to expected argument type 'FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!'"


code was-

var params = ["url" : "image"]
        var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/pagename/photos", parameters: params, httpMethod: "POST")
        request?.start(completionHandler: {(connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, result: Any, error: Error) -> Void in
        })